# Поиск кратчайшего пути до нескольких точек

Tags: алгоритм, графы, дерево

Есть множество точек, расстояние между каждой можно вычислить (можно считать что расстояние есть). Из них несколько опорных (заданы изначально). Каждую точку, кроме опорных, надо соединить с одной из опорных точек отрезком минимальной длины, не превышающим заданной длины. Если точка дальше заданного расстояния до всех опорных, можно соединить через другую точку - создать промежуточную точку (но и с ней отрезок должен быть не больше заданной длины). В конце все точки должны быть соединены с опорными (некоторые через промежуточные), но промежуточных точек должно быть как можно меньше (одна промежуточная может соединять несколько конечных с опорными, даже если через неё у некоторых конечных расстояние больше, чем через другие).

С какой стороны искать решение? Все решения графов ориентированы на поиск пути из точки А в точку Б, не нашел как рассчитывать по принципу 'многие ко многим' ..

Comment: *но промежуточных точек должно быть как можно меньше* критерий оптимальности - именно минимизация количества промежуточных точек? остальное всё пофиг?

Comment: по сути - да. Главное соблюсти условия - из любой точки можно добраться до одной из опорных, расстояние каждой линии не больше заданного значения, промежуточных точек минимум

Comment: Может быть, на алгоритмы кластеризации посмотреть?